# How to update Table A, when there are conditions in Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a query that updates a SQL Server table (Table A) value in column 3 only on the include condition that is present in Table B and in column 2 (pref) of Table A

The primary key on both tables is `Employee_number`.

And the condition in Table B active or inactive

```
Select Distinct employee_number 
from dbo.tableB  
where employee_number not in (select distinct employee_number 
                              from dbo.tableA 
                              where pref Pref = 'work') 
  and active_or_inactive = 'a'


Update TableA
Set value = “good”
Where employee_number from dbo.tableB  
where employee_number not in (employee_number 
                              from do.tableA 
                              where Pref = 'work') 
  and active_or_inactive = 'a'
```

Comment: Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: A [mre] with sample data and desired results would make your question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear how everything fits together in the sample code, but try this:

```
UPDATE a
SET value = 'good'
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM TableB b
        WHERE b.employee_number = a.employee_number
            AND b.active_or_inactive = 'a'
   )
   AND a.Pref='work'
```